# Does the browser rearrange HTML if it violates some conditions

Tags: html, google-chrome, templates, browser

I have a template that is dynamically generating html like

```
<span>
  <p> Words words words </p>
  <div> <span>text</span></div>
</span>
```

But when I check the rendered html, what I get is more like

```
<span><span>
<p>Words words words</p>
<div><span>text</span></div>
```

Comment: Could you add an actual [mcve]? (emphasis on verifiable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Browsers are able to "fix" broken code quite well nowadays.
The problem here: you are nesting block elements inside inline elements. Please change the outer span to a div!

If you need help fixing it - Please tell more about the template, is it js or php code? Post the code if possible.

Comment: Since the browser is not eligible to change elements, it is fixing your nesting structure.

Comment: The example involves a lot of moving parts including 3rd party libraries that I cannot alter the behavior of.  They return a span, and I replace the contents with block elements.  I'm good as far as a solution goes, however.

Comment: well, a span can only have... span inside. Nothing else. (There are some other inline items, but they should not be used).

"The example involves a lot of moving parts including 3rd party libraries" - why?
Better write your code, either JS, or php, whatever you prefer. The code you produce now is invalid. And there is no good way to fix it with JS afterwards.